# How to test react functional component correctly using jest and enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

**my-component.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";

const UnitTest = () => {
  const [todo, set_todo] = React.useState({});

  React.useState(() => {
    const onMounted = async () => {
      const getTodo = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
      set_todo(getTodo.data);
    };
    onMounted();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="UnitTest">
      <p>{todo.title}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UnitTest;
```

**api response**

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
}
```

**my-component.test.js**

```
import { mount } from "enzyme";

import UnitTest from "../../src/pages/unit-test";

describe("UnitTest component", () => {
  let wrapper = mount(<UnitTest />);

  it("should render the component", () => {
    wrapper = mount(<UnitTest />);
    console.log(wrapper.debug());
    expect(wrapper.find("p").text()).toEqual("delectus aut autem");
  });
});
```

**test result**

[image]

How to make my `<p>` tag contain `delectus aut autem` when console.log(wrapper.debug()) and is it possible if i want to update the state (set_todo) to be

```
{
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "second title",
    "completed": true
}
```

from my test file and update the assertion become     `expect(wrapper.find("p").text()).toEqual("second titile");` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jest.spyOn(object, methodName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) method create mock for `axios.get()` method and its resolved value.

Use [act()](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act) with `promise` and `setTimeout` to create macro task to wait the promise of `axios.get()` method created to be resolved in `useEffect` hook.

E.g.

`MyComponent.jsx`:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react';

const UnitTest = () => {
  const [todo, set_todo] = React.useState({});

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const onMounted = async () => {
      const getTodo = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
      set_todo(getTodo.data);
    };
    onMounted();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="UnitTest">
      <p>{todo.title}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UnitTest;
```

`MyComponent.test.jsx`:

```
import UnitTest from './MyComponent';
import axios from 'axios';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

const whenStable = async () => {
  await act(async () => {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
  });
};

describe('67885144', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const axiosGetSpy = jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: { title: 'delectus aut autem' } });
    const wrapper = mount(<UnitTest />);
    await whenStable();

    expect(wrapper.find('p').text()).toEqual('delectus aut autem');
    expect(axiosGetSpy).toBeCalledWith('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
    axiosGetSpy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67885144/MyComponent.test.jsx (7.902 s)
  67885144
    ✓ should pass (45 ms)

-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File             | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files        |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 MyComponent.jsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.499 s
```